# OpenSSL behavior when called from TCL exec

Tags: openssl, tcl

I'd made a script that pipes a text string as a variable through echo to an exec call to openssl, and it works fine. Recently, we've run into the limit of echo, and so used << in the exec call to re-direct the value of the text variable, from this:

```
set lines [exec echo $tte | openssl enc -a -$cipher -md $digest -nosalt -pbkdf2 -pass pass:$key]
```

to this:

```
set lines [exec openssl enc -a -$cipher -md $digest -nosalt -pbkdf2 -pass pass:$key -- << $tte]
```

and then just add the -d when we decipher.

After encryption, some additional encrypted information is disbursed throughout the ciphertext, including salting and hashing guides, and prior to deciphering, that stuff is removed, and this worked well, as it did after changing the way the text variable is passed to openssl. We now have discovered that with shorter text strings, and we're not sure if there's a hard limit, but openssl will return an empty string when deciphering, and we're at a loss as to why. De-bugging with tk_messageBox's we find that if we comment out the added salting and so on, it will work fine, even though it's receiving the exact same text string as when we insert the salting and hashing information. We went as far as hashing the texts between both methods to be sure.

Our horrible fix is to simply "if" the text string length is > 1024 use << else use echo, but I hate stupid fixes like that. Any ideas?

Comment: note that `echo $tte | ...` adds a newline to the string. `exec ... << $tte` does not. So, it's not the exact same text string.

Comment: I did mistakenly leave out the -n after echo when I typed that in, I couldn't copy and paste I don't have that setup in my VM

Comment: Did you try the `-nopad` option? You might be running into problems with strings below the length of a minimum cipher block size. Reading between the lines and based on experience, these encryption algorithms really prefer to work on multibyte chunks of data, not arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, adding a `-A` in addition to the lower case `-a` in the openssl command line makes it work, apparently does some buffer flushing